# Evaluate the Binomial Coefficient

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, combinatorics

Given two nonnegative integers `n,k` such that `0 <= k <= n`, return the binomial coefficient

```
c(n,k) := (n!) / (k! * (n-k)!)
```

#### Test cases

Most languages will probably have a built in function.

```
c(n,0) = c(n,n) = 1 for all n
c(n,1) = c(n,n-1) = n for all n 
c(5,3) = 10
c(13,5) = 1287
```

#### Related challenges

[Catalan Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66127/catalan-numbers)  [Compute the multinomial coefficient](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69424/compute-the-multinomial-coefficient) [Generate Pascal's triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/generate-pascals-triangle) [m-nomial coefficient](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78343/m-nomial-coefficient)

Comment: Surely this is a dup http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/mathematical-combination/9150#9150 or am I missing something?

Comment: I was not aware of that, and I did a thorough search / had it in the sandbox for quite a long time. Too bad it doesn't contain the keyword *binomial coefficient*...

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
f=(n,k)=>k?n*f(n-1,k-1)/k:1
```

Answer (score 5):

## MATL, 2 bytes

```
Xn
```

[try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WG4&input=NQoz)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5/8//9/Q@P/pgA)

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
l~S*\0e]e!,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59TF6wVY5Aam6qo8/@/obGCKQA)

#### Explanation

This uses a trick that (I think) I first used [for the Catalan numbers challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66130/8478). CJam doesn't have a built-in for this, and computing three factorials is too expensive. But the binomial coefficient `c(n,k)` is the number of ways we can select `k` out of `n` elements. That is, it's equal to the number of permutations of a list of `n` elements where `k` of them have one value and the remaining have another.

```
l~   e# Read and evaluate input. Dumping n and k on the stack.
S*   e# Get a string of k spaces.
\0e] e# Pad to length n with zeros.
e!   e# Get the unique permutations.
,    e# Count the number of such permutations.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 8 bytes

There is a builtin for this calculation:

```
nchoosek
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
n#0=1
0#k=1
n#k=(n-1)#(k-1)*n`div`k
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 8 bytes

```
Binomial
```

Yup. Sample usage: `Binomial[13,5]` or `13~Binomial~5` to obtain `1287`.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
n#k|k<1||k>=n=1|m<-n-1=m#(k-1)+m#k
```

Usage example: `13#5` -> `1287`.

A variant with the same size for the `k<1||k>=n`test is `n*k-k*k<1`.

Comment: ​Very​ ​clever!​​​​

Answer (score 2):

## J, 1 byte

```
!
```

#### Usage:

```
   3!5
10
   5!13
1287
```

Comment: Also works in APL.

Answer (score 1):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 6 bytes

```
pCi
 i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@1/gnMmlkPn/v6ExlykA)

`C` is the built-in for binomial coefficients, the `i`s are replaced with one input each, `p` prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:k<1or n*f(n-1,k-1)/k
```

Note that this will return *True* if **k = 0**, which [seems to be allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9067/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCnk22VbWOYX6SQp5WmkadrqJOta6ipn/2/oCgzr0QhTcNUx1iTC8YxNNYx1fwPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
.cF
```

A program that takes input in the form `n,k` and prints the result.

[Test](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.cF&input=13%2C5&debug=0)

**How it works**

This simply folds `c(n,k)` over the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

Input is of the form `k<newline>n`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@/9oWsf//8ZcpgA)

```
█
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 23 bytes

```perl6
{+combinations $^n,$^p}
```

```perl6
{[*] ($^n...0)Z/1..$^p}
```

( Both are were based on code found at [examples.perl6.org](http://examples.perl6.org/categories/best-of-rosettacode/binomial-coefficient.html), and [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients#Perl_6) )

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
:i:&G-:h/p
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Omk6JkctOmgvcA&input=MTAwCjkw)

This does the computation manually, without the builtin:

```
:     % Take input n implicitly. Range
      % STACK: [1 2 ... n]
i:    % Take input k. Range
      % STACK: [1 2 ... n], [1 2 ... k]
&G-   % Push n and k again. Subtract
      % STACK: [1 2 ... n], [1 2 ... k], n-k
:     % Range
      % STACK: [1 2 ... n], [1 2 ... k], [1 2 ... n-k]
h     % Concatenate the top two arrays horizontally
      % STACK: [1 2 ... n], [1 2 ... k 1 2 ... n-k]
/     % Element-wise division
      % STACK: [1/1 2/2 ... k/k (k+1)/1 (k+2)2 ... n/(n-k)]
p     % Product of array. Implicitly display
      % STACK: 1/1 * 2/2 * ... * k/k * (k+1)/1 * (k+2)2 * ... * n/(n-k)
```